# i have stored array in database as a string how can retrieve that array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have saved this array as `String` in my database :

```
Array
(
    [item_number1] =>1
    [payment_date] => 04:21:34 Dec 06, 2014 PST
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [first_name] => sdfsd
    [last_name] => parsdfsdandekar
    [quantity1] => 1
)
```

Now, I want use all array values.

How can fetch them ?

Comment: Did you serialize() it for storing.

Comment: how do you store it in database can you display here ?

Comment: If you do that, either serialize it or convert it into a json. NEVER store a blank array in a database.

Comment: Emm... how did you store that array? did you store that as a serialized array or as a json string? (or did you just paste that array structure a a peace of text in the DB (in the latest case it is not usable as you can not parse that in to a propper php array).

Comment: ya i have just pasted array structure to db

Comment: is there any any way to get those array values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JSON_ENCODE` first before saving the array to DB ,then use `JSON_DECODE` if you want to get again the contents

```
     $arr = array(
        "item_number1" => "1",
        "payment_date" => "04:21:34 Dec 06, 2014 PST",
        "payment_status" => "Completed",
        "first_name" => "sdfsd",
        "last_name" => "parsdfsdandekar",
        "quantity1" => "1"
     );

     echo json_encode($arr);
```

Result after `JSON_ENCODE` (Array to JSON String):

```
{ "item_number1" => "1", "payment_date" => "04:21:34 Dec 06, 2014 PST", "payment_status" => "Completed", "first_name" => "sdfsd", "last_name" => "parsdfsdandekar", "quantity1" => "1" }
```